# persist row checkbox selection in grid with pagination

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a javascript code with Kendo grid, when I do a search and obtain results, I should be able to select items from the grid with a checkbox. The problem comes when I change page and select more items, selected items from page 1 dissapear. 
I am able to store selected item in an array, but the actual checkbox from the selection is not retained, which makes the grid think there are no selected items.

Following is a piece of the code I have that stores the selected items in an array.

```
groupMemberSearchGridOnDataBinding = function (e) {
  $(clsContentPanel).has(gridId).show();
  if (e.items.length === 0) {
    $(divGroupMemberSearch).attr(style, display + displayNone);
    $(plusMinusSearchMemberClick).addClass(clsPlus).removeClass(clsMinus);
    $(plusMinusSearchMemberClick).addClass(pnlCollapsed);
    $(toggleButton).find(hr).show();
    $(groupMemberCancelButton).show();
    $(groupMemberSaveButton).hide();
    hideLoadingDialog();
  }
  else {
    var grid = $(gridId).data("kendoGrid");
    var grid_radio = $(gridId).data(kendoGrid);
    var row = $(inputChecked, grid_radio.tbody).closest("tr");
    var gridDiagnosisData = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < row.length; index++) {                
      var selectedMemberInfo = {
        GroupPolicy: {
          MemberID: grid.dataItem(row[index]).TPLMemberID,
          MemberNumber: grid.dataItem(row[index]).TPLIndividualID,
          MemberName: grid.dataItem(row[index]).GroupMemberName,
          RelationshipDesc: "",
          CostAvoidanceDesc: "",
          CostAvoidanceDenialReasonDesc: "",
          PolicyDetailId: "",
          IsAdd: true,
          IsValid: true
        }
      };
      gridDiagnosisData.push(selectedMemberInfo.GroupPolicy)
    }
    if (row.length > 0) {
      retainCheckBoxSelection();
    }
    $(divGroupMemberSearch).attr(style, display + displayNone);
    $(plusMinusSearchMemberClick).addClass(clsPlus).removeClass(clsMinus);
    $(plusMinusSearchMemberClick).addClass(pnlCollapsed);
    $(toggleButton).find(hr).show();
    $(groupMemberCancelButton).show();
    $(groupMemberSaveButton).show();
    hideLoadingDialog();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can be done in two steps.**

1. Save the row selection in an array using the change event
2. Preserve the row selection by the iterating array in the data-bound
   event

First Telerik documentation already has an [documentation link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/persist-row-selection-while-paging#persist-row-selection-during-data-operations)

**Finally**, on how to select a row here is the running [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/uGayU)